# How to ignore untracked files when using CocoaPods?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, cocoapods

I have a simple project and wanted to include a third party library (CocoaLumberjack) using CocoaPods. After creating the simple Podfile I ran `pod install` in my project directory. Everything worked fine, except I now have untracked files in my project that are marked with question marks in Xcode:

[image]

Is this how it's supposed to be? I don't remember having these question marks when I last used CocoaPods in a different project. Shouldn't CocoaPods automatically set up the correct gitignores for the pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods doesn't do anything with your `.gitignore`.

I recommend using [GitHub's Objective-C `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore) (at least as a starting point). Alternatively, just make sure you ignore the `Pods` directory by adding an entry for Pods in your ignore file:

```
# CocoaPods
Pods
```